# Flowgear SQL Watcher

Tags: flowgear

How do I configure the SQL Watcher trigger in Flowgear?  The config options screen does not contain a field where I can enter the actual Query whose results need to be monitored.  Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing.[image: The SQL Watcher config screen]

Also, what is the difference between the "Notify" and the "Poll" options in the "WatchMethod" dropdown?

Comment: Hello @Shawn de Wet
You have done SQL watcher configuration, please give be one example how it is configure in flowgear.i will do like when my table record is updated it that time flowgear sql watcher fire and get only updated row.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first create the connection then add an instance of the SQL Watcher to a workflow and select the connection you've just created. There is then a field on the SQL Watcher node in which you can specify the SQL query you'd like to execute.

The Poll option in Watch Method will check the database at the specified WatchPollInterval to check for changes. The Notify method will use Sql Query notification instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If I set the WatchMethod to Poll, and the FireOn to RowsChanged, is the logic built into the connection of such a nature as to detect a change in rows since the last poll?

Comment: Yes, that's right it will poll every WatchPollInterval seconds and each time a change is detected it will provide you with the data to be consumed by the following node which is hooked up in your workflow.

Comment: We've updated the documentation on the node, check it out at https://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Node:SQL_Watcher

Comment: Hello @CamW
Please give me one example workflow for SQL watcher.i will do like when my table record is updated it that time flowgear sql watcher fire and get only updated row.Thanks